# can I use UF B cable to wire a dryer?

Tags: dryer, nec

Can UFB cable be used for wiring my dryer?  Normally I'd just run some NM able, but I found a good deal on 8 AWG UF B and wonder if this is code compliant (NEC 17) or not....or maybe there is another unforeseen problem.

Comment: As long as it's 10 ga, you should be fine. I'm not posting this as an answer bc I'm not sure. You mentioned THHN which would go in conduit. Are you running conduit?  Normally NM cable in most areas would suffice.   UF would be hard to pull thru conduit and is a PITA to work with, but as long as you pay attention to fill capacity of conduit, I think it's code legal. Wire pricing is very weird right now. Another recent post mentioned UF being cheaper than NM, which makes little sense, other than it's strictly market based pricing.

Comment: @George Anderson It's actually 8 gage, so bonus for me!  Sorry, my brain hasn't kicked on yet today.  I'd normally rum NM or THHN if I have conduit.  No conduit here...I'll update the question.

Comment: Thanks George.  I'm at the store and don't have access to my NEC.

Comment: It would be overkill and no fun, but if you enjoy a challenge go for it! NEC says it has to be installed  according to the rules for NM, and isn't limited to the 60°C amperage limits when installed as NM.

Comment: Finding a "good deal" on 8 ga uf is unusual, but if so great for you.   Is it 8/3 with ground? For many years now, dryer circuits require a 4 wire feed:  2 hots, a neutral and a ground.  In the past 3 wire feeds were normal, but not now.   Also, you may have some trouble getting 8 ga wire into a 30 amp breaker.

Comment: @George Anderson Good point.  I'm upgrading from 8/2 to 8/3 and we have a 40A breaker.  Even if I don't use it for the dryer 8 gage at $0.62/ft is too good to pass up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, this is fine as long as it's 8/3

UF is permitted anywhere where NM can be used, in addition to its more traditional uses outside/underground, and an 8AWG wire certainly has enough "grunt" to carry a 30A dryer circuit, so as long as this is an 8/3 W/G UF cable you're talking about, then you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the dryer receptacle will be a NEMA 14-30.  Since it is a 30A receptacle, you will be required to use a 30A breaker.  NEC 210.21(B).

Remember for wires any larger than this, aluminum wire is your friend.  Even in today's market, 4-wire #2 aluminum feeder (90A) is only $1.40/foot.  You either select sockets rated for aluminum wire... or go to a main-lug subpanel (which is definitely rated for aluminum; the lugs are aluminum).

Answer (score 1):

UF is used the same as NM because it is NM but the nonmetallic cover is heavier and there is not paper that could wick water so yes you can use UF to wire the dryer. As others have suggested you need 4 wire and depending on the code version in use for your jurisdiction possibly a GFCI breaker.